# How to embed videos using TinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm working on Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I've installed TinyMCE (last version). For a start, it displays correctly on my website, but I found out it cannot show embedded videos. So, I googled for this, but no luck.

Does anybody knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The tinymce forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/) is your friend. There are many threads concerning video issues. 
Have a look at solutions there using the search phrase "youtube". Most approaches are using the [media plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/media).

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution there.

Comment: glad to have been able to help you